# laravel default image not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

i am new to laravel and im facing this problem:

i have this code in registerController:

```
 protected function create(array $data)
{
    $pic_path="";
    if($data['gender'] =='male'){
        $pic_path = 'http://localhost:8000/img/profile-default-male.png';
    }else if($data['gender'] =='female'){
        $pic_path='http://localhost:8000/img/default_women.jpg';
    }
    return User::create([

        'name' => $data['name'],
            'pic' => $pic_path,
        'gender' => $data['gender'],
        'slug' => str_slug($data['name'],'-'),
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

but in register.blade.php: i have this

```
   <img src="{{asset('/img/default_women.jpg')}}" width="80px" height="80px">
```

i know that i have to put this:`Auth::user()->pic` inside the img src but i tried a lot and its not working

also i got this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'pic' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `gender`, `slug`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (w, Female, w, w@w.com, $2y$10$xcgYVa2xcgBctTgvBSK2n.HaZ4vJt2MmlSmJ5Fxx80bZqvPfHrILi, 2017-09-12 00:49:41, 2017-09-12 00:49:41))
```

so any help will be appreciated thank you

Comment: You tried a lot and what isn't working?  Your error doesn't seem to coincide with your code since it's saying 'pic' isn't set.

Comment: i mean that i have 2 problems: field pic with no default value and i am pretty sure that img src is wrong @Devon

Answer (score 0):

Laravel protects against mass assignment vulnerabilities by limiting what fields you can mass assign.

You'll need to add the `pic` attribute to the `$fillable` attribute in your `User` model:

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        ..., 'pic' //ensure pic is in the array
    ];
}
```